# Minimal Scala monad containing either good values or error messages?

Tags: scala, monads

In Scala, I am thinking of a simple monad `Result` that contains either a `Good` value, or alternatively an `Error` message. Here is my implementation.

I'd like to ask: Did I do something in an excessively complicated manner? Or mistakes even?

Could this be simplified (but maintaining readability, so no [Perl golf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Golf_Apocalypse))? For example, do I need to use the abstract class and the companion object, or could it be simpler to put everything in a normal class?

```
abstract class Result[+T] {
  def flatMap[U](f: T => Result[U]): Result[U] = this match {
    case Good(x) => f(x)
    case e: Error => e
  }
  def map[U](f: T => U): Result[U] = flatMap { (x: T) => Result(f(x)) }
}
case class Good[T](x: T) extends Result[T]
case class Error(e: String) extends Result[Nothing]
object Result { def apply[T](x: T): Result[T] = Good(x) }
```

Now if I, for example

```
val x = Good(5)
def f1(v: Int): Result[Int] = Good(v + 1)
def fE(v: Int): Result[Int] = Error("foo")
```

then I can chain in the usual manner:

```
x flatMap f1 flatMap f1    // => Good(7)
x flatMap fE flatMap f1    // => Error(foo)
```

And the for-comprehension:

```
for (
  a <- x;
  b <- f1(a);
  c <- f1(b)
) yield c    // => Good(7)
```

P.S: I am aware of the `\/` monad in Scalaz, but this is for simple cases when installing and importing Scalaz feels a bit heavy.

Comment: Is `Try` / `Success` / `Failure` unacceptable? It's a quasi-monad.

Comment: `Try` is a bit limited, as `Failure` can only contain values that are exceptions.

Comment: What about using *Either* . It looks a lot like you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: `Either` is unbiased, it does not default to the `right` field, so `flatMap` and `for` comprehension won't work, one needs to explicitly choose the `right`field every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me. I would change the `abstract class` into a `sealed trait`. And I think you could leave off the return types for `flatMap` and `map` without losing any readability.

I like the companion object because it calls out your unit function for what it is.

Comment: *I would change ...* why?

Comment: Ah, yes, `sealed trait` enables the compiler to check that pattern matches over `Good` and `Error` are comprehensive. (Also `sealed abstract class` would do the same, but it's longer to write.)

Comment: Thanks for answering om-nom-nom's question Sampo.

Comment: After a certain point I basically abandoned using `abstract class` in Scala - unless I need a constructor with one or more parameters. Traits are just a lot more flexible and fluid to work with. And like you point out, the are more succinct to declare.